# Power Query 'an evaluation is in progress' when merging

Tags: powerquery, msbi

When merging two tables in PowerQuery an evaulation is run to determine the possible number of matches. I run pretty large tables (merge a 10K record table with a 500K record table) so this can take a long time.

I know there will be matches because I have done this before and I am not a beginner. Yet PowerQuery insists on running this behaviour.

Is there anyway to baypass this step? It almost feels like when you just need to turn automatic calculation off in Excel so that you can get on with actually doing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: To make this even worse it then loads all the rows into the Editor. Seems like a waste of resources when I haven't finished constructing my query yet...

Comment: So much time waiting for 'Unexpected error: Out of Memory'

Comment: Lets try applying a filter first... opps "Limit of 1000 values reached"

Comment: Time to learn MDX formula and advanced query editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would add in an upstream filter to limit the rows e.g. Keep Rows / Keep Top Rows / 100.  You may need to do this on both Queries. Ideally you Keep enough rows or use a specific filter to get some matches, to help your downstream Query design work.

Then once the query design is finished, I would remove the filter(s) and let it rip.

This is what PQ should be doing in the Query Editor, but it does seem to go rogue on Merge in particular.

Comment: Sensational. Thanks for the help. I'll give it a try and come back. Does that just place an SQL 'LIMIT'??

Comment: It depends.  They call that "Query folding", (PQ logic gets "folded" into the SQL SELECT.  It wont happen downstream from any step that it cant translate into SQL.  So insert the Keep Rows as early as possible.

Comment: Any ideas how to turn on Query Folding in PowerBI? This link suggests https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3635/query-folding-in-power-query-to-improve-performance/ using SQL Server Profiling but as I am not system admin on our SQL Services on Azure I don't think I can get it. I'm just an analyst and not IT.

Comment: Maybe I could hack this just by applying a filter to another filed (ie users starting with 'A') to limit the data and then remove this later. Or would that be occurring too late in the query?

Comment: "Users starting with 'A'" would probably work.  You can't "turn on" Query Folding - the PQ engine decides.  You can only monitor it using SQL Profiler.  Add your filter as far up the Step list as possible to encourage Folding.